# How to dismiss progress bar from repository?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-progressbar

I am using MVVM pattern with repository for network call.

When i click button in my view it triggers save/ fetch data method in my viewmodel which then make call to repository wherein i am doing my network operation using Retrofit.

Now i would like to dismiss my progress bar with proper message (like saved, error etc. from my repository (onResponse or onFailure) that i started inside view.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("saving...");
            dialog.show();
            cuttingUnitViewModel.saveProjectUnit();
        }
```

Is it ok to do what i am doing or is there better alternative?

All i want to say that I want to return NETWORK STATE and DATA both from repository , how to do that?

Comment: are you not making use of a LiveData to update your results? How are you managing passing the result you get back to your activity. if your are doing so, simply write the code to hide the progress bar when you get the results in your activity/fragment

Comment: @ljk  1. I am getting response object when i am fetching data. 2. I am returning Void when saving data. other than this i also need to handle when there is response failure.

Comment: My experience is here: https://medium.com/@ostap.radkovskyy/lessons-learned-mvvm-and-livedata-18e10f8e3550 Basically you either use event wrappers, or one time event, or what @ljk suggests. But not a single scenario is perfect unfortunatley.

Answer (score 1):

Main issue which I think in your case is that you initiate a call and get its response but your activity doesn't get to know any of these changes. Without this you might have to create some custom util classes or some other workaround which in my opinion would be a really bad practice.

My suggestion is that you create a `MutableLiveData` object for your response in your activity's `ViewModel`, then pass this object to your repository so that when your retrofit completes your call you can post the result on your livedata object.

And in your activity you should be observing this livedata for changes. So, when you get the result and post the new value, then in activity livedata observer's `onChanged()` you can get the result and even make your progress bar disappear.

Sorry, if this was too hard to understand. Here is a nice [little tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1) you can refer to. I suppose that would make things easier with an example. Good luck!

Comment: And also i want to change message and icon of progress bar before getting dismissed, or should i use somekind of dialogue separately for this?

Comment: If you have a look at the tutorial you'll get a better idea. Basically you can pass the whole response in your livedata. so when its onChanged is triggered you can retrieve the complete data and write whatever you were planning on doing the repository for response success/failure. Like hiding the progress bar or showing a message all in your active view itself.

Comment: Then i need to track two live data in my repository? One for actual JSON response that i am getting from network (if any) and another for different type of situation like (success, failed, error etc)

Comment: I think you are getting too confused. You will have one mutable livedata in your viewmodel and one getter function returning the LiveData to observe the changes. This single livedata you will need to pass to your repository and use postvalue method there. In your activity observe this single livedata, so when the value gets posted it will trigger the change in your activity where you were observing this livedata.

Comment: All i want to say that I want to return NETWORK STATE and DATA both from repository , how to do that? @ljk

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not proper to do `View` activities like dismissing `ProgressBar` in the Repository as this class is only meant to deal with Data from different sources and this creates tight coupling. A proper design would be to set callback functions back to the class where the `View` is present from the Repository class through the intermediate layers like `ViewModel` until it reaches the View layer and then dismiss the `ProgressBar` there.